# I'm stuck at creating a view by excluding the rows with fields having NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've the below table Sales with the data

| Sales_quantity | Plant_name | hierarchy_level | Product_line | Customer_group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 254.6 | USW1 | ELS | NULL | Z001 |
| 84 | WDC2 | NULL | E24 | Z001 |
| 6578 | UAE1 | ELIB | D47 | Z082 |
| 234 | BD1 | ELBD | NULL | Z038 |
| 765 | IN5 | ELIK | I56 | Z002 |
| 27.3 | CH1 | ELIK | C72 | NULL |

From the above table, ideally the rows having null values should be excluded in the view.

I added not null constraint but it didn't work. Please help me with this. I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only want to exclude rows having null for the `Product_line` column, or something else?

Comment: So you deleted your prior question and reposted - just without the image. Unfortunately, it is still difficult to understand your goal. Can you try `select ... from xxx where Product_line is not null`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes I want to exclude the rows having null values

Comment: @SMor that will help but if there are lot of columns having null values.. in that case how can I write the query. not sure which question I've asked before

Comment: Have you looked at this post? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14864/test-if-any-columns-are-null

Comment: _how can I write the query_ Using the same syntax repeated for each column that can have NULL. There is no real shortcut though I can think of a kludge that might achieve the result. But let's start by writing the query correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.V_NotNullSales',N'V')IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW dbo.V_NotNullSales;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.V_NotNullSales
AS
 SELECT S.Sales_quantity, S.Plant_name,S.hierarchy_level,S.Product_line,S.Customer_group 
 FROM Sales AS S
 WHERE S.Sales_quantity IS NOT NULL 
  AND S.Plant_name IS NOT NULL 
  AND S.hierarchy_level IS NOT NULL AND S.Product_line IS NOT NULL 
 AND S.Customer_group  IS NOT NULL
GO
```

Comment: `CREATE OR ALTER VIEW` is easier than a conditional `DROP`